# difference between two dates for every unique value in another coloumn

Tags: r

I have data with the customer IDs and dates the customer was interacted with. I would like to create a new variable that shows how long a customer has been in touch with in days

```
  Customer ID | Date of Contact
       211         2015-02-24          
       211         2015-06-17          
       211         2015-08-11          
       202         2015-01-02          
       202         2014-06-19          
       194         2015-07-28
```

The idea is that for every customer the new variable should calculate the number of days between his latest interaction and oldest interaction. So for example in the customer of customer ID 211, it will be the number of days between 2015-08-11 and 2015-02-24 (168 days)

If there has only been one interaction with a customer, then the days should be 0 (as is the case with customer ID 194)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do "grouped" calculations. I like `data.table` for it; it is also good at ready the data.

```
R> suppressMessages(library(data.table))
R> dt <- data.table::fread("id  Date
+ 211         2015-02-24          
+ 211         2015-06-17          
+ 211         2015-08-11          
+ 202         2015-01-02          
+ 202         2014-06-19          
+ 194         2015-07-28")
R> dt[, Date:=as.IDate(Date)]                     ## make sure it is 'Date' type
R> dt[, .(duration=max(Date)-min(Date)), by=id]
    id duration
1: 211      168
2: 202      197
3: 194        0
R>
```

The key here is that given the id, the calculation really is just the "range" of the dates, ie max minus min.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::summarise`

```
df %>%
    group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
    summarise(diff = max(Date_of_Contact) - min(Date_of_Contact))
#  Customer_ID diff
#        <int> <time>
#1         194 0
#2         202 197
#3         211 168
```

---

### Sample data

```
require(tidyverse);
df <- read_table(
    "Customer_ID  Date_of_Contact
       211         2015-02-24
       211         2015-06-17
       211         2015-08-11
       202         2015-01-02
       202         2014-06-19
       194         2015-07-28")
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R you could do this.

```
df$Diff <- as.integer(ave(as.character(df$Date_of_Contact), df$Customer_ID, FUN = function(d) as.Date(d) - as.Date(d[1])))
df
#  Customer_ID Date_of_Contact Diff
#1         211      2015-02-24    0
#2         211      2015-06-17  113
#3         211      2015-08-11  168
#4         202      2015-01-02    0
#5         202      2014-06-19 -197
#6         194      2015-07-28    0
```

Or, if you want just the difference between the first and the last dates,

```
tapply(df$Date_of_Contact, df$Customer_ID, FUN = function(d) d[length(d)] - d[1])
# 194  202  211 
#   0 -197  168
```